# Unable to update the user_meta data using the wp function

Tags: php

I am trying to update user meta using the following code but it does not work

'''

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    //get user details from user table and user_meta table
    $current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
    $user_info = get_userdata($current_user->ID);
}        if (isset($_POST['ProfBtn'])) {         

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $oldfirstname = $current_user->first_name;
    echo"new first name is" .$firstname ."<br>";

    if(!isset($_POST['firstname']) || $_POST['firstname'] != $oldfirstname){

        echo"new first name is" .$firstname."<br>";
        update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['firstname']);   
   }
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, I replaced

`update_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'first_name', $_POST['firstname']);`

with

`update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, 'first_name', $_POST['firstname']);`